# Why can't I open anything I download from the internet?

Tags: downloads

Every time I try to download a program, it goes straight to archive manager. I don’t know what to use in order to open anything I download.  What should I do?

Comment: Because Archive Manager is opening, I assume you are downloading some sort of compressed archive.

Comment: Please be more specific. What type of program is it (script/binary/something else)? Usually programs that you download cannot be executed directly until you make them executable. e.g. by using chmod +x, or in GUI left click on program, select properties, tick executable check-box.

Answer (score 0):

Go under Options -> General tab

Under Downloads select ask where to save files.